# How to fix the gap after hiding a column in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportviewer, ssrs-2008-r2, report-viewer2010

That might be simple but I couldnt solve it for hours.

I use Microsoft Reporting Services 2008 R2 and ReportViewer 2010. I have a table in one of my reports having three columns like:

```
Name Age Gender
Jack 20   M
```

What I want is to hide Age column based on a parameter. I am doing it by giving it an hidden expression like:

```
=IIF(Parameters!check.Value=1,true,false)
```

However, when the column becomes hidden the output is:

```
Name          Gender
Jack          M
```

THere is a gap between name and gender now. I need to have an output like

```
Name Gender
Jack M
```

without gap. I couldnt manage to provide it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It should work if you select the entire column, right click and go to `Column visibility...` menu then set that expression in the Show or hide based on an expression.

Comment: oh yes! I was writing in a wrong area ("hidden" instead of "column visibility"), Thanks my friend. Make it an answer I will select it correct ans.

Comment: Your logic was correct but you did not know where to use the expression so I posted the answer as Community Wiki since it was solved in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you select the entire column, right click and go to `Column visibility...` menu then set that expression in the `Show or hide based on an expression` textbox.

[image]

[image]